# Read from System.in from another Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, stdin

I'm currently developing a console application, which observes multiple directories with the Java 7 WatchService API.
While in the main method the observation loop takes place, I want a separate thread to read from the `System.in` stream to check whether the observation must stop.

My `Runnable` implementation looks like this:

```
public class InputHandler implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean keepRunning = true;
        int readBytes = -1;
        byte[] readChunk = new byte[8];

        System.out.println("Starting directory observation ...");
        System.out.println("Type 'stop' to end directory observation.\n");

        while (keepRunning) {
            try {
                readBytes = System.in.read(readChunk);

                if (readBytes > 4) {
                    keepRunning &= !(new String(readChunk).contains("stop"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Failed to read input!");
                keepRunning = false;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nDirectory observation stops now ...");
    }
}
```

My main method does this:

```
// Prepare the WatchService stuff ...
Thread ihThread = new Thread(new InputHandler());

do {
    WatchKey watchKey = directoryWatch.take();

    for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
        if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
            // do something
        }
    }

    keepRunning &= !Thread.State.TERMINATED.equals(ihThread.getState())
            && watchKey.reset();
} while (keepRunning);
```

When I run the code, no message is printed and I can't write anything in the command line. How can I access the 'main' `System.in` and `System.out` from the new thread?

Comment: I built DataFetcher back in the day for exactly this kind of purpose. Eventually, I got too tired of always re-writing custom threaded readers, so I created this general solution: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/

Comment: Have you started the thread? I don't see `ihThread.start()` anywhere.

Comment: `System.in` is a public static field.  You can access it from any method at any time.

Comment: Thanks @Codebender, didn't see that